# Base fields are absolute, how to position next fields in CSS (auto coming in from drpl) not with the name of each class separate because too many

Tags: css, drupal, css-position

I have a `div: position:relative;`, inside that div I have next divs:

```
-price: position:absolute; top:10px;
-quantity: position:absolute; top:30px;
-add to cart button: position:absolute; top:30px;
```

I do this to position the quite nicely, otherwise drupalwise not 100%. So after that other field are coming automatically in that div, but I do not want to style them each by name of the class, because are just too much to keep track of in CSS

Can I say to CSS, for next fields that come in just place them as from top:50px; for example? How?

Comment: ?? set a parent in absolute, then let other div come in as usual

Comment: drupalwise maybe possible by adding a field group and giving that fieldgroup a class that i can make absolute and let the other come in, nice workaround, but not a css solution

Comment: nop, CSS is not a programming language, just styling, no way for it to find & calculate next free spot :), but the parent in absolute to hold   them whole, is the way to handle this. It will also allow overflowing the container, just saying :)